# Ошибка сборки Gradle

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Gradle ругается на последнюю фигурную скобку. Где ошибка?

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' //enter the latest version
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }
allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взгляните еще раз на блок `dependencies` и обратите внимание на то, какую ошибку вы допустили

```
uildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' //enter the latest version
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }
allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо вам большое за помощь! Чтобы я без вас делал)